# Octave GUI on Mac is not able to open a file

Tags: mac, octave

I entered this code on my octave GUI on Mac:

```
 3.> cd /Users/Sudipta/Downloads
warning: load_path: .: Operation not permitted
QKqueueFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: open: Operation not permitted
Warning: QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /Users/Sudipta/Downloads
```

It is showing that the operation is not permitted

I am using macOS Big Sur and Octave version 3.8.0. The file in question exists in my computer. How can I open the file? Can someone please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: MacOS put some restrictions on some directories like Downloads. For command line instructions (python…), I havevto copy a file from Downloads to the Documents with the finder… then I can access them with my instructions.